# display:none does not work

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that the `display:none` command seems to not have any effect. The elements are still visible. So this is my JavaScript:

```
function hideShow(object) {
    element = document.getElementById(object);
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
        element.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The 'object' argument is an ID attribute of an element to be hidden. This is the HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="button2" value="New" onClick="hideShow('new');">

<form action="some url" id="new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="vm" value="5" class="button3">
<input type="submit" class="button2" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't show us the code where you call your function.

Comment: Can you show us the call of `hideShow()`?

Comment: Updated @Sirko, it was in the original post but they hadn't indented it.

Comment: Also, is `element` a global `var`? If not you may want to specify `var element = document.getElementById(object);`

Comment: you have to cancel the button from taking action on the form!

Comment: [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/5SC5w/)

Comment: Putting your code through jsfiddle is giving me `ReferenceError: hideShow is not defined`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G3BPw/ it works already

Comment: @DanielA.White — No, it isn't a submit button and it isn't in a form.

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console when this fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the code in the jsfiddle.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/8bMUP/1/)

```
<input type="button" class="button2" value="New" onClick="hideShow('new');">

<form action="some url" id="new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="vm" value="5" class="button3">
<input type="submit" class="button2" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    function hideShow(object) {
    element = document.getElementById(object);
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
        element.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
    </script>
```

I hope it solves your problem.

And if not, then please provide further details and comments for the same.

Regards.